# pgfplots: How to set true dimensions of axis

Tags: pgfplots, dimensions, axis

I would like to have axis dimensions in real TeX units.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xmin=0,
      xmax=1,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=1,
      xtick=\empty,
      ytick=\empty,
      width=4cm,
      height=2cm,
    ]
    \addplot[mark=none]{x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\rule{4cm}{2cm}
\end{document}
```

How to have the left rectangle of the tikz picture and the black rectangle of the TeX rule with exactly the same size?

[image]

The method should work whatever dimension is given (2cm and 4cm are only examples).

**NB:** The preamble was added *after* rmano's comment.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to TeX.SX. Please, post complete MWE next time. You can achieve what you need by adding `scale only axis` to the options of the `axis` environment.

Comment: As an addition to Rmano's answer: the reason the axis becomes smaller is that `pgfplots` subtracts a bit from the specified size to make room for ticklabels and axis labels (unless `scale only axis` is used). It doesn't currently do any calculation of the size of the labels, instead it just sets the size of the axis box to 45pt less than the specified size. Hence, in this case  `width=4cm+45pt, height=2cm+45pt,` gives the same result as `width=4cm, height=2cm, scale only axis`. I'd rather use the `scale only axis` version though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick is `scale only axes`, which applies the dimensions only to the axis (when you add ticks, titles and so on the bounding box of the graph will be bigger, of course).

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xmin=0,
      xmax=1,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=1,
      xtick=\empty,
      ytick=\empty,
      width=4cm,
      height=2cm,
      scale only axis,
    ]
    \addplot[mark=none]{x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\rule{4cm}{2cm}
\end{document}
```

[image: big boxes]